# External function modifying structure array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm new to C, so I'm hoping to learn as much about external functions and pointers and structures here as I can

My idea: create an array of structures and then write "external" functions (i.e. functions saved in different files than my main program) that I can use to modify the fields in the structures in my structure array.

My effort:

```
extern void fillMass(Body *p, int size)

typedef struct body Body;
int main() { 
body bodies[n]   /* creates an array of structures of type body (yes this is a hw problem) */
int sizeBodies = sizeof(bodies)/sizeof(struct body);
Body *planets;
planets = &bodies[0]; 
fillMass(planets, sizeBodies);
}
```

This works when I have fillMass defined below Main.  But I'd like to define it in another file, so I tried making fillMass.h (I first used fillMass.c but then found lots of examples where people did things like this and used include statements to include their external functions, which I guess requires a .h file...? Or is that just a convention?)
So I wrote a simple file called fillMass.h

```
void fillMass(Body* p, int size) {    /* this is line 10 of the code */
  p[0].mass=99;
  p[1].mass=350;   /*just testing, not using size parameter */
}
```

But this doesn't work.  I get the error

```
fillMass.h:10: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

Any thoughts?  And this is a problem with fillMass.h; when I get this working, should I be able to do what I set out to do without much difficulty?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Tha means that `Body` is not defined when the compiler reaches line 10 of fillMass.h. You must define ths structure `Body` in fillMass.h

Comment: semicolon after "p[0].mass=99"?

Comment: Also, you tagged this as `c` and `c++`, however those are different languages. And in neither language is `body bodies[n]` legal, it should be `Body bodies[n];`. Please copy-paste your code or check carefully for typoes if typing it out!

Comment: @MattMcNabb, in c++ `body bodies[n];` will work, actually, if `struct body` exists.

Comment: His code doesn't have the trailing semicolon, so the compiler would see `body bodies[n] int sizeBodies...` which is a syntax error. Also, whether or not it works with the semicolon depends on what `n` is, builtin arrays cannot have runtime sizing in C++ (although it is a common compiler extension to allow it)

Comment: @MichaelWalz  thanks, that was addressed below in an answer and it makes sense to me.  I'm getting a new error now though (please see my comment below the provided answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two files.

body.h

```
struct body{
    int mass;
    //other elements
};
typedef struct body Body;

void fillMass(Body* p, int size) {    /* this is line 10 of the code */
    p[0].mass = 99;
    p[1].mass = 350;   /*just testing, not using size parameter */
}
```

main.c

```
#include "body.h"

int main() {
    const unsigned n = 5;
    //you should determine n
    Body bodies[n];   /* creates an array of structures of type body (yes this is a hw problem) */
    int sizeBodies = sizeof(bodies) / sizeof(Body);
    body *planets;
    planets = bodies; //the same as &bodies[0]
    fillMass(planets, sizeBodies);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a complaint about an "undefined reference to main" when I try to compile body.h.  Help?

Comment: Thank you dear user2198121 for giving me something I can understand.  I'm now changing to a new way for coding this - all of my "body" related things (structure definition, methods, etc..) are in "body.h", and my use of them is in main.cpp.

Comment: @blaughli, sorry, I surely meant "main.c". Nevertheless you should determine either you program on C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

add a '**;**' behind the  p[0].mass = 99.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have the choice

to declare the struct with a typedef.

```
typedef struct body{
  int mass;
}Body;
```

and then the function:

```
void fillMass(Body *p, int size)
```

**OR** not typedef the struct

```
struct body{
  int mass;
};
```

and then the function will be:

```
void fillMass(struct body *p, int size)
```